# Google Cloud IKEv2 VPN on Ubuntu Compute Engine VPS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, vpn, iptables, vps

As I stated in the title, I am installing the strongSwan and configure the IKEV2 VPN on the VPS.

But, as you know, GCP has its firewall rules, which I am not familiar with that.

I am using this script to install strongSwan IKEV2 VPN (https://github.com/truemetal/ikev2_vpn)

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport  500 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 4500 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD --match policy --pol ipsec --dir in  --proto esp -s 10.10.10.10/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD --match policy --pol ipsec --dir out --proto esp -d 10.10.10.10/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.10/24 -o eth0 -m policy --pol ipsec --dir out -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.10/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD --match policy --pol ipsec --dir in -s 10.10.10.10/24 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -m tcpmss --mss 1361:1536 -j TCPMSS --set-mss 1360

iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP
```

Someone can help me to apply those rules into GCP firewall rules?

Comment: Questions about the Linux operating system and its utilities are off topic here and should, instead, be asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or, possibly, https://serverfault.com/ Please delete this and ask over there. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: If you would like to know how to apply and setup the firewall rules you need for your GCP project to use strongSwan, I would suggest looking at this document here: https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/configuring-firewall-rules

Comment: Consider using [cloud-vpn](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs)